# Gatsby Smooth Scroll Anchor Links doesnt work when deployed to github pages

Tags: javascript, gatsby, smooth-scrolling, gatsby-plugin

I have a Gatsby website which consist of a few pages. On the navbar, there are different links. Some links point to different pages while some links will bring you to that particular section on that page with a smooth scrolling effect.

TO achieve this, I used Gatsby smooth scroll anchor links. Documentation is here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-anchor-links/.

This is basically what Im trying to achieve:

*Many sites use a mixed navigation format in which some links route to other pages, while some anchor a smooth scroll to sections within a specific page — but both types still need to function well regardless of what page the user is currently on.*

Here's a snippet of my navbar code:

```html
<MDBNavItem className="mr-4">
   <AnchorLink to="/#buy-now" 
               title="Buy AIEOU">
       <span>Buy AIEOU</span>
   </AnchorLink>
</MDBNavItem>
<MDBNavItem className="mr-4">
   <AnchorLink to="/about" title="Our team">
       <span>About Us</span>
   </AnchorLink>
</MDBNavItem>
```

What's odd is that it totally works fine when I use it locally. But it doesnt work anymore when I deploy it to Github pages. Instead of the smooth scrolling, it just teleports to that section instead. I added the offset options and also the StripHash attribute but it still doesn;t work. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have everything well configured as it seems and that you say that it teleports to the sections (the behavior is correct, the effect not) I guess you need to add the following CSS rule to add smooth behavior:

```
html,
body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

The fallback for the browsers at [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-behavior).

Comment: Yayy, it works if I add in that CSS! Im just not sure why it would work when I run the local server but will not work when its deployed. Thanks though :-)